# How to populate a UIView with image and Label?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiimageview, uilabel

I need to build a view where i can have a scale kind of thing such as the small and tall images below which there are numbers.
| ! ! |
assume the bigger line as the whole numbers and the smaller ones as partitions.
I want to replicate this kind of scenario many time.

Is there a way to do this??

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Build it in interface builder and load it by

UIView * v = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:nil] objectAtIndex:0];